# Undefined reference on a binding to id, Scoping rules

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to pass around an object required by some qml components. The problem is that I cannot reference this object without it saying its undefined.

```
Item {
    id: root

    property alias db: database // this works for some reason

    Database {
        id: database
        Component.onCompleted: {
            connect("sqlite3", "dbname=database.db")
            deleteTables();
            createTables();
        }
    }

    ContactImageProvider {
        id: contactImageProvider
        database: db // this works for some reason
        database: root.database // This would be undefined
        database: database // no loop detected but still null
    }
}
```

So I am very very confused how I am supposed to be able to pass dependencies down though objects without the most confusing naming scheme ever. This could be anything BTW. Maybe I need a color in some control but want to pass it to another control as well. The whole scope name resolution documentation is very unclear. I can't make heads or tails what I'm supposed to be able to do.

```
Item {
    id: root

    property Database database: Database {
        id: database // if no id then this doesnt work
        Component.onCompleted: {
            connect("sqlite3", "dbname=database.db")
            deleteTables();
            createTables();
        }
    }
    property alias db: database

    ContactImageProvider {
        id: contactImageProvider
        database: db // this doesn't work. WHY? idk
        database: database // works if id is on
    }
}
```

Also aliasing doesn't seem to work if I make it a property.

Comment: `database: db // this doesn't work. WHY? idk` - db is not an id, it is a property and is not "globally" available, you have to go for `root.db`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any poor soul after me, it seems that this has to do with the differences between how property names and id names are resolved. What I ended up with was this.

```
Item {
    id: root

    property Database database: Database {
        // notice no id
        Component.onCompleted: {
            connect("sqlite3", "dbname=database.db")
            deleteTables();
            createTables();
        }
    }

    ContactImageProvider {
        id: contactImageProvider
        database: root.database // I can explicitly get a property
    }
}
```